# Independence of Features assumption in Naive Bayes

Tags: probability, naive-bayes-classifier, naive-bayes-algorithim

How do we know if your features in my dataset are independent before applying Naive Bayes? Basically I want to know is it possible for us to get an idea before training our model if Naive Bayes will give decent results on it.

Answer (score 1):

Statistical independence is a pretty straightforward thing. If $$p(A\cap B) = p(A) p(B)$$ then $A$ and $B$ are independent (in other words if marginal distributions are equal to conditional). If you want, you could even check that on your data. Though it would be easier to check:
$$p(A|B) = p(A) \ \text{and} \  p(B|A) = p(B)$$ instead of constructing a joint distribution. The latter is easy, if your features are categorical then you could estimate  $p(A)$, $p(B)$ , $p(A|B)$, $P(B|A)$ as sample frequencies. If one of A or B is categorical computations are also simple. If both A and B are numeric, you need to fit a KDE (kernel density estimation) model to all probability distributions.

However, on practice it is simpler and faster just to fit a Naive Bayes and check its performance on a test set.

Answer (score 0):

You could try computing [Mutual Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) between the features ([sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif.html) can do it).

You could estimate [Pearson's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) or [Spearman's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) correlation coefficients

You could try training similar models to predict one feature given another, and use accuracy to determine.